# Use large variables without using much memory

Tags: c++, variables, memory-usage

I've wired up a dot matrix, and I display characters on the screen by using something like the example code below.

The `Char_B` variable is a global variable in a library used by the Arduino, and `displayPixels()` is called from inside the library.

```
bool Char_B[8][8] = {
{0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0}
};

displayPixels(1000, Char_B);
```

However, each time I declare a new character like the array above, I use a relatively massive amount of memory. Is there any way to reduce memory usage? Keep in mind I am willing to change the structure of the array if necessary, since I'll need well over 100 characters loaded onto the Arduino to write text.

Comment: As a first step, pack your bits.

Comment: `I use a relatively massive amount of memory.` - 64 bytes, perhaps? You don't need 64 bytes to store 8 lots of 8 bits. You would need 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

The data structure will take 64 bytes as sizeof bool is 1 byte not a bit. The first option is to pack each line (or column) in a byte (or bytes). The prefix 0b is for [binary constant value](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) (in gcc).

```
uint8_t Char_B[8] = {
0b01111000,
...
0b01111000
};
```

The second option is to move the data structure to program memory.

```
const uint8_t Char_B[8] PROGMEM = { ... };
```

This will require reading each line with a special [function](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#ga73084a8bbde259ffae72980354b3f027).

```
for (int line = 0; line < sizeof(Char_B); line++) {
  uint8_t pixels = (uint8_t) pgm_read_byte(Char_B + line);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a single byte to store a row of data. As a bool still takes a single byte.

Optionally you could flip the axis, and store column data, instead of row data in the array. Since letters like `i` use fewer columns that letters like `B`. Even in your example you can see you have 3 columns with only `0`s.

A final suggestion would be to use `PROGMEM` and use the `pgm_read_byte_near` function. That way the data will remain in the flash memory, and will not take any space in the program-memory.

Comment: PROGMEM is an excellent idea. That saves storing anything in RAM.